# Is the ABS going to make problems because of the different tire height between the front and the rear?

Tags: tires, abs, opel, wheels

I'm going to buy tires for my Opel Vectra b 97 fwd. I've been driving with 4 205/45/17 but now I've found 2x205/45/17 and 2x215/45/17 used. I know that there will be a little difference in the height.

Is the ABS going to make problems because of the different tire height between the front and the rear. (If I put the wider/higher tires at the rear and the smaller tires at the front)?

Comment: This really depends on the specific tires being used. It seems every manufacturer measures their tires a little differently, even the same manufacturer between product lines can be vastly different. Don't use *just* the numbers to come up with what the rotations/mile (RPM) is going to be. You can go to several different online tire stores which have the RPMs, you just need to find your exact model.

Answer (score 1):

based on the results from the site :
https://tiresize.com/tyre-size-calculator/
the 205 is 857 revs / mile and 215 is 844, which gives a 1.52% difference - will this affect the abs - probably as a wheel only has to slip a small amount for traction control etc to react.

My personal feeling is to not purchase second hand tyres, you never know how they have been treated : kerbed, internal damage etc

Comment: Well they are DOT 2016 and they look great. I was going to buy new ones, but my car is worth about 1000$ here and new tires for my rims are about 400$ so I am afraid that someone will steal my car just for the rims and the tires :D.